What is the equation relating the sides and the orthocenter segments of a triangle?
I'm trying to set up an equation relating the orthocenter parts (e.g. $v_1$, $v_2$) to a, b and c. Since I don't know many theorems, I'm in a lot of equation confusion. So far I have been able to describe u, v and w with Heron's area formula $u=\frac{2A}{a}$, $v=\frac{2A}{b}$ and $c=\frac{2A}{c}$ thanks to this I can reach $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ but then when I proceed with the Pythagorean theorem I can come up with too many Quadratic equation systems I am lost in equations. I would be very grateful if you can help, maybe there is an easier way or an application that you can do faster.

Geogebra project

Hint:
$(u_2:v_2:w_2)$ are the trilinear coordinates of the orthocenter.
Accordingly, $(a u_2:b v_2:c w_2)$ are the (non-normalized) barycentric coordinates of the orthocenter.
For the latter, the linked ETC entry gives rational expressions in terms of $a,b,c$.
This allows you to derive equations for $u_2,v_2,w_2$ in terms of $a,b,c$, up to some (yet undetermined) common scaling factor.
(Proving any of the formulae given for $X(4)$ should pave the way for proving the rest.)
As to the scaling factor: Your $u_2,v_2,w_2$ need to satisfy the area equation
$$a u_2 + b v_2 + c w_2 = 2A$$
Or equivalently, when eliminating $a,b,c$ in favor of $u,v,w$:
$$\frac{u_2}{u} + \frac{v_2}{v} + \frac{w_2}{w} = 1$$
Besides, $(u_1:v_1:w_1)$ are the tripolar coordinates of the orthocenter,
which the ETC gives as well, up to a common factor.

[+1] indeed trilinear coordinates (which are almost unknown, except participants to olympiads... and "clients" of ETC)  avoid to reinvent the wheel.


You can also use the properties of Euler points K,J and I which are the intersection of the nine point circle with altitudes of the triangle and also the properties of the circumcircle:
Considering picture:
1): properties of nine poits circle; H is where altitudes cross:
$OD=\frac{CH}2$
$OM=\frac {BH}2$
$OL=\frac{AH}2$
2): properties of circumcircle center O:
$OD=\sqrt{R^2-(\frac c2)^2}$
$OM=\sqrt{R^2-(\frac b2)^2}$
$OL=\sqrt{R^2-(\frac a2)^2}$
1-We have a, b and c, so we have the area  of the triangle S from Heron's formula and therefore we can calculate the radius of the circumcircle R as:
$R=\frac{abc}{4S}$
2- calculate OD, OM and OL
3-Calculate the measures of the heights AG, BF and CE.
4- calculate $CH(w_1), AH(u_1)$ and $BH(v_1)$.
5- Now you can find $HE(w_2),HG(u_2)$ and $HF(v_2)$.
